# Calculate hours between two dates excluding weekends in sharepoint calculated coloumn

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I wanted to calculate hours between two dates excluding weekends in SharePoint calculated column.

I can get the hours using following formula but not sure how to exclude weekends?

```
=TEXT([enddate]-[startdate],"h")
```

I got this formula which gives me date difference in days, hrs and minute excluding weekend -

```
=DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")-IF(WEEKDAY(EndDate)=7,FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+WEEKDAY(StartDate))/7,1)*2,FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+WEEKDAY(StartDate))/7,1)*2+1)+IF(WEEKDAY(StartDate)=7,2,1)&TEXT(MOD(EndDate-StartDate,1),"hh""""mm""""")
```

Applied the same but having following issue -
StartDate - 8/4/2016 12:22 PM
EndDate -   8/5/2016 9:22 AM

Calculated col with above formula gives me "12059" ie. 1 day, 20hrs and 59 min

Actually I have to put the logic if calculated col > 24 hrs , then have to do some actions...
But with above formula, if date changes, tehn it will give me 1 day always...

Comment: you might subtract 48 h. Will that solve your requirement?

Comment: There are at least 3 blogs out there with the answer, I don't have them at hand. Use Google

Comment: sure I will google it now,

Comment: Hi Patrick- Substract 48 hrs? Not getting this one...